# Are there disadvantages to using Rhizobium rhizogenes for genetic transformation?

Tags: genetics

Rhizobium rhizogenes causes hairy roots, which are transgentic. Are the transgentic roots able to eventually grow normal roots or will they always be hairy in the transgenic organism?

> After integration and expression, in vitro or under natural
>   conditions, the hairy root phenotype is observed, which typically
>   includes overdevelopment of a root system that is not completely
>   geotropic, and altered (wrinkled) leaf morphology, if leaves are
>   present.  - Cardarelli M, Mariotti D, Pomponi M, Spanò L, Capone I, 
>   Costantino P. 1987. "Agrobacterium rhizogenes T-DNA genes capable of
>   inducing hairy root phenotype". Molecular and General Genetics
>   209(3):475-480.

Is this permanent or temporary?